# ListView inside a fragment is not detecting clicks and setOnItemClickListener is not being called

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm adding a listView of trailers to my fragment.When an item is clicked it's supposed to start an intent to play the video but for some reason, the click is not detected

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.example.user.popularmovies.ItemActivityFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            tools:text="beauty and the beast"
            android:id="@+id/movie_title"
            android:padding="@dimen/tv_padding"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/empty_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/iv_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/iv_layout_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/iv_layout_marginTop"
            android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
            android:layout_below="@id/movie_title"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:text="beauty and the beast"
            android:id="@+id/movie_year"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/movie_title"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/movie_title"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/card_view" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:text="beauty and the beast"
            android:id="@+id/movie_rating"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_below="@+id/movie_year"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/movie_year"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/movie_year" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/v_layout_height"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/v_layout_margin"
            android:layout_below = "@id/movie_poster"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/black_line"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/black_line"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/black_line"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/tv_cardCornerRadius"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_above="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/movie_poster">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/movie_overview"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <ListView
            android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_below="@+id/movie_poster"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/empty_view" />

        <!-- Empty view is only visible when the list has no items. -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

    </RelativeLayout>



 </ScrollView>
```

and here's my onCreateView code

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container,  
   false);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) 
   rootView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        initComponents(rootView);
        setValues(rootView);

        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        ListView trailerListView = (ListView) 
   rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) 
rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        trailerListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

        //Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of earthquakes as 
         input
        mAdapter = new TrailerAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Trailer>());

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        trailerListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        // Set an item click listener on the ListView, which sends an intent to a web browser
        // to open a website with more information about the selected earthquake.

        // Get a reference to the ConnectivityManager to check state of network connectivity
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                rootView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Get details on the currently active default data network
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // If there is a network connection, fetch data
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
            android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

            // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
            // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
            // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
            loaderManager.initLoader(TRAILER_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, display error
            // First, hide loading indicator so error message will be visible
            //  View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
            //  loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Update empty state with no connection error message
            mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
        }
        trailerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Find the current trailer that was clicked on
                Trailer currentTrailer = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                String trailerLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + currentTrailer.getKey();

                // Convert the String URL into a URI object (to pass into the Intent constructor)
                Uri trailerUri = Uri.parse(trailerLink);
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this ,currentTrailer.getKey() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Create a new intent to view the trailer URI
                Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, trailerUri);

                // Send the intent to launch a new activity
                startActivity(websiteIntent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Adapter code

```
 public class TrailerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Trailer> {

public TrailerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Trailer> trailers) {
    super(context, 0, trailers);
}



/*    public TrailerAdapter(ItemActivity.PlaceholderFragment context, 
 List<Trailer> trailers) {
    super(context, 0, trailers);
}*/

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if there is an existing list item view (called convertView) that we can reuse,
    // otherwise, if convertView is null, then inflate a new list item layout.
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.trailer_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    // Find the earthquake at the given position in the list of trailers
    Trailer currentTrailer = getItem(position);

    // Find the TextView with view ID magnitude
    TextView nameView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    // Display the magnitude of the current earthquake in that TextView
    nameView.setText(currentTrailer.getName());

    // Return the list item view that is now showing the appropriate data
    return listItemView;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return super.areAllItemsEnabled();
}
 }
```

Fragment code

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Trailer>>{

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) rootView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        initComponents(rootView);
        setValues(rootView);

        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        ListView trailerListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        trailerListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

        //Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of earthquakes as input
        mAdapter = new TrailerAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Trailer>());

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        trailerListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        // Set an item click listener on the ListView, which sends an intent to a web browser
        // to open a website with more information about the selected earthquake.




        // Get a reference to the ConnectivityManager to check state of network connectivity
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                rootView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Get details on the currently active default data network
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // If there is a network connection, fetch data
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
            android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

            // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
            // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
            // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
            loaderManager.initLoader(TRAILER_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, display error
            // First, hide loading indicator so error message will be visible
            //  View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
            //  loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Update empty state with no connection error message
            mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
        }
        trailerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Find the current trailer that was clicked on
                Trailer currentTrailer = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                String trailerLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + currentTrailer.getKey();

                // Convert the String URL into a URI object (to pass into the Intent constructor)
                Uri trailerUri = Uri.parse(trailerLink);
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this ,currentTrailer.getKey() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Create a new intent to view the trailer URI
                Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, trailerUri);

                // Send the intent to launch a new activity
                startActivity(websiteIntent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void initComponents(View rootView){
        movie = new Movie();
        ItemActivity.intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        int movie_id = intent.getIntExtra("movie_id",0);
        int movie_position = intent.getIntExtra("movie_position",0);
        movie = MainActivity.moviesList.get(movie_position);
        movie_title = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        movie_year = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_year);
        movie_rate = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_rating);
        movie_poster = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
        movie_overview = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_overview);
    }

    public static void setValues(View rootView){
        movie_title.setText(movie.getOriginal_title());
        movie_year.setText( movie.getRelease_date().substring(0,4));
        movie_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        movie_rate.setText(movie.getVote_average() + "/10");
        movie_overview.setText(movie.getOverview());
        String movie_poster_url;
        if (movie.getPoster_path() == TMDB_API.IMAGE_NOT_FOUND) {
            movie_poster_url = TMDB_API.IMAGE_NOT_FOUND;
        }else {
            movie_poster_url = TMDB_API.IMAGE_URL + TMDB_API.IMAGE_SIZE_185 + "/" + movie.getPoster_path();
        }
        Picasso.with(rootView.getContext()).load(movie_poster_url).into(movie_poster);
        movie_poster.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<Trailer>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(REQUEST_URL);
        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();
        return new TrailerLoader(getActivity(), uriBuilder.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Trailer>> loader, List<Trailer> trailers) {
        /// Hide loading indicator because the data has been loaded
        // View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        // loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Set empty state text to display "No trailers found."
        mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_trailers);

        // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
        mAdapter.clear();

        // If there is a valid list of {@link Earthquake}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
        if (trailers != null && !trailers.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(trailers);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Trailer>> loader) {
        // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

I tried to add      android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"> to the XML as generally suggested, but didn't work

Comment: Did you try to add a break point? By the way, please update your fragment and adapter code as well

Comment: yes I did, the listener is not getting triggered when an item is clicked

Comment: android:clickable="false" remove from listview

Comment: doesn't solve it :(

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Was solved by adding the following to the RelativeLayout in the list item XML:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Additionally, if this does not work, try also getting rid of ScrollView altogether.